# Sqlite Problem Error ( sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: name)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a database SQLite with a gui tkinter the problem is that whenever i save the data the error shows.

def save(self):

```
    with sqlite3.connect('account.db') as db:
        c = db.cursor()

    # Find Existing username if any take proper action
    find_info = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = ?'
    c.execute(find_info, [(self.name.get()), (self.StudentNumber.get()),(self.attendance.get()),(self.quiz.get()),(self.project.get()), (self.actual.get()), (self.final_exam.get()),(self.final_Grade.get())])
    if c.fetchall():
        ms.showerror('Error!', 'Could not find DATA.')
    else:
        ms.showinfo('Success!', 'Data CREATED!')
        # Create New Account
        insert = 'INSERT INTO user (name, student number, attendance, quizzes, project, actual examinations) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
        c.execute(insert, [(self.name.get()), (self.StudentNumber.get()), (self.attendance.get()), (self.quiz.get()),
                            (self.project.get()), (self.actual.get()), (self.final_exam.get()),(self.final_Grade.get())])
        db.commit()
        self.moon()
```

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/IAC-PC8/PycharmProjects/SKIN/OB.py", line 241, in save
    c.execute(find_info, [(self.name.get()), (self.StudentNumber.get()),(self.attendance.get()),(self.quiz.get()),(self.project.get()), (self.actual.get()), (self.final_exam.get()),(self.final_Grade.get())])
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: name
```